# Finally convert from MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This has been in the pipeline for sometime, i have never really touched base with MySQLi but i have the two following statements below, how easy or what is different to convert these to MySQLi?

This is my select statement that gets information and makes them available using PHP within the document (`<? print $getUserMoney; ?>`)

```
$qryy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User` = 'Username' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$arry = mysql_fetch_array($qryy);

$getUserMoney = $arry['money'];
$getUserEmail = $arry['email'];
```

This is the insert statement that is used.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Users` ( `Id` , `User` , `Email`)
VALUES
( '' , 'Username' , 'Email')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I know these statements are really outdated.

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service and there are some posts online that explain the process.

Comment: Did you, well, *try* to implement these using `mysqli`?  Where did you get stuck?  Since these are static queries with no parameters, they should be *fairly simple* to execute in any data access technology.